# How to add dictionary in url as query param python request

Tags: python, query-string

Actually i am calling 3rd party API and requirement in to add json dictionary as it is. refer below URL example

> https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/getTxnStatus?JsonData={"MID":"MID117185435","ORDERID":"ORDR4o22310421111",
>   "CHECKSUMHASH":
>   "NU9wPEWxmbOTFL2%2FUKr3lk6fScfnLy8wORc3YRylsyEsr2MLRPn%2F3DRePtFEK55ZcfdTj7mY9vS2qh%2Bsm7oTRx%2Fx4BDlvZBj%2F8Sxw6s%2F9io%3D"}

The query param name in "JsonData" and data should be in {} brackets.

```
import requests
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus
import urllib.request
import urllib

data = '{"MID":"MID117185435","ORDERID":"ORDR4o22310421111","CHECKSUMHASH":"omcrIRuqDP0v%2Fa2DXTlVI4XtzvmuIW56jlXtGEp3S%2B2b1h9nU9cfJx5ZO2Hp%2FAN%2F%2FyF%2F01DxmoV1VHJk%2B0ZKHrYxqvDMJa9IOcldrfZY1VI%3D"}'

jsonData = data

uri = 'https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/getTxnStatus?jsonData='+str(quote_plus(data)) 

r = requests.get(uri)
print(r.url)
print(r.json)
print(r.json())
```

print(r.url) output on console

> https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/getTxnStatus?jsonData=%7B%22MID%22%3A%22MEDTPA37902117185435%22%2C%22ORDERID%22%3A%22medipta1521537969o72718962111%22%2C%22CHECKSUMHASH%22%3A%22omcrIRuqDP0v%252Fa2DXTlVI4XtzvmuIW56jlXtGEp3S%252B2b1h9nU9cfJx5ZO2Hp%252FAN%252F%252FyF%252F01DxmoV1VHJk%252B0ZKHrYxqvDMJa9IOcldrfZY1VI%253D%22%7D

It converts {} to %7B and i want {} as it is..

Plz help  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to undo quote_plus by importing and using unquote_plus.

I didn’t test against your url, just against your string.

When I print your uri string I get this as my output:

> https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/getTxnStatus?jsonData=%7B%22MID%22%3A%22MID117185435%22%2C%22ORDERID%22%3A%22ORDR4o22310421111%22%2C%22CHECKSUMHASH%22%3A%22omcrIRuqDP0v%252Fa2DXTlVI4XtzvmuIW56jlXtGEp3S%252B2b1h9nU9cfJx5ZO2Hp%252FAN%252F%252FyF%252F01DxmoV1VHJk%252B0ZKHrYxqvDMJa9IOcldrfZY1VI%253D%22%7D

If I surround it like this:

```
print(str(unquote_plus(uri)))
```

I get this as output:

> https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/getTxnStatus?jsonData={"MID":"MID117185435","ORDERID":"ORDR4o22310421111","CHECKSUMHASH":"omcrIRuqDP0v%2Fa2DXTlVI4XtzvmuIW56jlXtGEp3S%2B2b1h9nU9cfJx5ZO2Hp%2FAN%2F%2FyF%2F01DxmoV1VHJk%2B0ZKHrYxqvDMJa9IOcldrfZY1VI%3D"}